# vs2008 won't let me Imports System.Deployment.Applications

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, deployment

I am Using Visual Studio 2008 sp1 for a WPF application with Visual Basic.  I am trying to use the line "Imports System.Deployment.Application" so I can use ApplicationDeployment to create a button to manual check and install updates to my application.  However, I get a message that "Application is not a member of deployment".  I have constantly researched this and I can't figure out why this isn't working especially considering I am using common methods to create a button to check for and install updates.  Obviously I am missing something.  The only member System.Deployment is "Internal".  How do I get the "Application" member to show up?  Thank you much!

Comment: I just answered my own question.  I just added a reference to system.deployment.  Duh!  Sometimes it's just better to get some sleep and figure it out in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a reference to system.deployment